# dap-mode: Initialize request failed: "program" property is required for launch

Tags: debugging, dap

I am trying to use LLDB to debug my rust code. To edit the code, I use `rustic-mode` with `lsp-mode`, and to perform debugging I am trying to use `dap-mode`.

Currently, this is how I initialize dap-mode in my init.el:

```
(use-package dap-mode
  :ensure t
  :config
  (dap-ui-mode)
  (dap-ui-controls-mode 1)
  
  (require 'dap-codelldb)
  (require 'dap-gdb-lldb)
  ;; installs .extension/vscode
  (dap-gdb-lldb-setup)
  (dap-register-debug-template
   "Rust::LLDB Run Configuration"
   (list :type "lldb"
         :request "launch"
         :name "LLDB::Run"
     :gdbpath "rust-lldb"
         ;; uncomment if lldb-mi is not in PATH
         ;; :lldbmipath "path/to/lldb-mi"
         )))
```

(almost a carbon copy from [here](https://github.com/rksm/emacs-rust-config/blob/master/init.el), but I don't check for presence of lldb-mi and `'dap-lldb` was replaced with `'dap-codelldb` since the former didn't seem to work at all)

Now, when I try to `M-x dap-debug` in my code, select the Rust template, and... A frame `*Warnings*` appears with the following message:

```
Warning (emacs): Initialize request failed: "program" property is required for launch Disable showing Disable logging
```

Now, that project also has launch.json generated by the CodeLLDB extension for VSCode, and dap-mode seems to recognize it. However, if I select the `Debug executable 'projectname'` template (that is generated and used by VSCode), same thing happens as when I use the debug template from the `init.el`, `"program" property is required for launch`. I was unable to find what that `program` property is, or what it should be set to, anywhere.